# Access props from selector's resultFunc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a similar use case as in the [accessing react props in selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors) docs, but in my case let's say the `visibilityFilter` comes from the props. Is there a way how to achieve something like below?

```
export const getVisibleTodos = createSelector(
  getTodos,
  (todos, props) => {
    // props is undefined 
    switch (props.visibilityFilter) {
      case 'SHOW_ALL':
        return todos
      case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
        return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
      case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
        return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    }
  }
)
```

I still need it to be properly memoized, but I guess that's the second step.

Answer (score 1):

[Props (or `ownProps`) is the second argument passed to any `mapStateToProps` function.](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments)

Using that, you can extract the property you want as one of the inputs to your `resultFunc`.

```
export const getVisibleTodos = createSelector(
  getTodos,
  (state, props) => props.visibilityFilter,
  (todos, visibilityFilter) => {
    switch (visibilityFilter) {
      case 'SHOW_ALL':
        return todos
      case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
        return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
      case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
        return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    }
  }
)
```